# Where do you normally keep your UNIX/Linux scripts?

Tags: unix, scripting, aix

There are numerous scripts that I have written for my server. Some of them are in my `~/scripts` and some of them are in application directories.

I am just wondering is there a directory that you would normally use to keep your shell scripts?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Personal ones for my account, `~/bin`.  System-wide ones go in `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/local/sbin` as appropriate (scripts which should only be run as root go in `sbin`, while scripts intended to help ordinary users go in `bin`), rolled out via configuration management to ensure that all machines that need them have them (and the latest versions, too).

Comment: You should explain the appropriateness of `bin` versus `sbin` :)

Comment: sbin is meant for "Superuser BINaries", programs that usually need root access to run properly. "bin" is for all the rest.

Comment: The origin of sbin came from "Statically-linked BINaries". When /usr (and its shared libraries) were mounted outside of single-user mode, it was found necessary to keep around some statically linked programs (sh, tar) that *always* worked. Since only the SysAdmin was interested in these binaries, the misnomer began.

Comment: I wondered about that too, I fear none of my scripts are worthy of the distinction :)

Comment: I do the same thing but with an extra level of directory for $ARCH -- so ~/pub/$ARCH/{bin,man,share} to allow for i386, x86_64 and any other architectures you have binaries for (I used to use SGI machines and various Sparcs, so this was more useful then :)

Comment: If you're managing to write architecture-specific shell scripts, I weep for whoever else has to maintain your code.

Answer (score 8):

For more complex stuff, especially something that could be shared between multiple machines I tend to make distribution packages, Debian in my case. I use `/usr/bin`, and give scripts some common prefix. That way it's easier to deploy and keep track of them. For my personal stuff, `~/bin` is good enough.

Comment: Is there a good guide somewhere for packaging (for Debian) simple scripts?

Answer (score 5):

At the moment I use ~/bin for my personal (quick and dirty :P) scripts and /usr/local/bin (or sbin) for system wide ones

Both directories are under revision control via git.

Comment: i do the same, except s/git/svn/

Answer (score 3):

I currently use /usr/local/$company/scripts for system-wide scripts, and ~/bin for personal. I also have a ~/code folder that contains work-in-progress stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I use ~/.bin
The folder is hidden for file managers and `ls`: i rarely modify anything inside, so let it be :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mix your own scripts with scripts placed in `~/bin` by installed packages and programs, you can store your scripts in a directory of your choice and bind it to `~/bin`. Your scripts will be visible in `~/bin` and you will be able to run them from a terminal with a simple name without having to specify a path.

For one time use you can run this command (effect will disappear after reboot):

```
sudo mount --bind ~/path-to-your-scripts-directory ~/bin
```

You can create a new script with this command and run it automatically at login to remount this binding after a reboot.

Or

To bind permanently, add these lines to `fstab`:

```
# bind my scripts to ~/bin
/home/myaccount/path-to-your-scripts-directory /home/myaccount/bin     none    bind    0   0
```